# CSS styles disapear when adding media attribute to html?

Tags: html, css

I have a very confusing problem and I'm not sure what's wrong. My CSS styles completely disappear when I add the media attribute to the link tag in the head of the html file. When I remove the attribute, the styles show up just fine. But I need this attribute to set the size for the display. Here is what I have in my head:

```
 <head>
 <title>Learning Addition</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="DesktopCss.css" media="screen and (max-width:481px)" > 
 </head>
```

Anyone know what the problem can be? Thanks.

Comment: You're telling the document not to apply the stylesheet if the screen is bigger than `481px`. I'm assuming your screen is larger than that, thus the stylesheet is not loaded.

Comment: PS, it sounds like you think this attribute will force the screen to be limited in size. That is not the case. This attribute tells the document when to use the stylesheet you provided.

Comment: Maybe you mean to do something like `body { max-width: 481px; }` instead? What's the goal of that media query?

Comment: I changed it from max to width and it worked but when I decrease the size of my window on the browser, the styles still go away. Do you know how to keep the styles on even if you decrease the size of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just copied the media query without understanding what's happening in it. Or else you simply overlooked the error in it.

Your query defines that this css file should be used only up to maximum screen size of 481px. Which is highly likely what you're not trying to do.

You should change `max-width` to `min-width` to make it work.

Also one more change that I would recommend is using all small case in the file name of your css file, and also changing the original name of your file on your server to small case, to avoid browser incompatibility issues.

Your code should look something like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Learning Addition</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="desktopcss.css" media="screen and (min-width:481px)" > 
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to load CSS that will apply to a desktop browser, unless you're using the world's smallest monitor, you should be saying

> screen and (**min**-width:481px)